# Exposing two ports in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to create a Pod in the Google Container Engine where two ports are exposed: port 8080 is listening for incoming content and port 80 distributes this content to clients?

The following command to create a Pod is given as example by Google:

```
kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node --port=8080
```

I can't seem to define a listening port, and when adding a second "--port=" switch only one port is exposed. 
Is there a way to expose a second port or am I limited to one port per container?

Comment: As pointed out by caesarxuchao, you are not limited to 1 port per pod. But IIUC your app is receiving data (say via http post, or raw tcp) on 8080 and receiving requests from backends (say via http get, or raw tcp) on port 80? Instead of using a simple pod I'd recommend a multiport service for such cases: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/services.md#multi-port-services

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, you cannot specify multiple ports in `kubectl run`. But you can use `kubectl create` to create a replication controller, and specify multiple ports for the container.

https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml has an example:

```
ports:
- containerPort: 7000
  name: intra-node
- containerPort: 7001
  name: tls-intra-node
- containerPort: 7199
  name: jmx
- containerPort: 9042
  name: cql
```

Comment: another good example here, uses multiple protocols:  https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk/

Comment: I believe the first line is over-indented

Answer (score 4):

If required through the helm, it can be achieved as:

**deployment.yaml**

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.containerport1 }}
          #name: containerport1
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.containerport2 }}
          #name: containerport2
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.containerport3 }}
          #name: containerport3
```

The service file needs to have a port name else it will give a render error.

**service.yaml**

```
  ports:
  - name: containerport1
    protocol: TCP
    port: {{ .Values.exposedport1 }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.containerport1 }}
  - name: containerport2
    protocol: TCP
    port: {{ .Values.exposedport2 }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.containerport2 }}
  - name: containerport3
    protocol: TCP
    port: {{ .Values.exposedport3 }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.containerport3 }}
```

The values can be set using the --set parameter while installing helm chart.

**values.yaml**

```
containerport1: 8001
containerport2: 8002
containerport3: 8003
exposedport1: 8004
exposedport2: 8005
exposedport3: 8006
```

Comment: do the names in **deployment.yaml** and **service.yaml** have to match?

Comment: No not necessarily that's easier to identify. You can name them differently. However I didn't try it, but if you have multiple ports in a service file, the name field is necessary else your service file will not be parsed. Also as you can see in the deployment file the name field has been commented out, the reason it's not necessary field for the file to get parsed. So yes the port names can be different. That's your answer whether to name ports in deployment file or not but to name them for sure in service file of k8s.

Answer (score 2):

Pointed out in another answer using kubernetes allows targeting, but also multiple ports:

```
kubectl expose deployment example --type=LoadBalancer --port 8080,8081 --target-port 80
```

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, it is possible to specify multiple ports using the **--overrides** option:

This example exposes both ports 80 and 8080:

```
    export APP_NAME=app-hello
    export IMAGE=gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
    kubectl run $APP_NAME \
                --image=$IMAGE \
                --overrides='{"spec": {"template":  {"spec": {"containers": [{"name": "'$APP_NAME'", "image": "'$IMAGE'",
 "ports": [{"containerPort": 8080, "protocol": "TCP"}, {"containerPort": 80, "protocol": "TCP"}]}]}}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes supports a target port:

`kubectl expose deployment example --type=LoadBalancer --port 8080 --target-port 80`

Answer (score -2):

You can use --port paramater two times
kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-node --port=8080 --port=8081

Comment: The original question here though, and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38859), say that this doesn't work - and [the docs say "The port" singular](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run). Has this changed?

Comment: It's also captured as a StringVar not a StringArray in the latest release: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.13.0-alpha.0/pkg/kubectl/cmd/run.go#L175

Comment: The above doesn't work for me the last port is the only one shown use kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].ports[*].containerPort}'  to check your ports