# Go http api server and socket.io

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently I'm working on a real-time online game. First I implemented a go server with socket.io for handling  messages between client and my game world and it works fine. Now for user data managing I need a http api for some functionality like login. I want to use awesome http/net package for that purpose. Should I serve the http server on different Port?

My next question is for deploying I want to use google container engine. Can I use pods with two ports open?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your explanation, you need two ports open for two different APIs running in your application. Regarding Exposing two ports in Google Container Engine, you can read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502022/exposing-two-ports-in-google-container-engine) that describes ways to expose ports in a pod.

Moreover, I invite you read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/high-alpha/a-cloud-native-api-part-1-google-cloud-and-kubernetes-8bcc75cb08e9) that involves deploying an API in a GKE cluster with a containerPort in a pod, Creating a Kubernetes service to allow internal cluster traffic to your pods (routing requests on an incoming port to your API targetPort), and creating an Ingress service to define what traffic is allowed into your cluster and where it goes. You can define different APIs with different targetPorts and run them on different pods. You can try it as an alternative. For more documentation on Exposing Applications using Services, you can read [this GKE doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps).